# Devops using packages from private Azure Artifacts feed: unexpected status code '404 Not Found'

Tags: azure-devops, nuget, yaml

My solution contains references to some private Nuget packages in a feed hosted in a Devops Artifact.

It builds on my machine.

However the Dev ops build fails because I need to set up access to the private Nuget Feed.

I am studying [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/package/nuget?view=azure-devops)

I have a nuget.config file in my solution with a reference to my private feed.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageRestore>
    <add key="enabled" value="True" />
    <add key="automatic" value="True" />
  </packageRestore>
  <activePackageSource>
    <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" />
  </activePackageSource>
  <packageSources>
    <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" protocolVersion="3" />
    <add key="MyFeed" value="myfeed/nuget/v3/index.js" />
    <!-- Others -->
  </packageSources>
  <packageSourceCredentials>
    <!-- secret stuff -->
  </packageSourceCredentials>
</configuration>
```

The NugetCommand task has an error (edited)

```
NU1000: Unable to find version 'myversion' of package 'MyPackageName'.
      C:\Users\VssAdministrator\.nuget\packages\: Package 'MyPackageName-Version' is not found on source 'C:\Users\VssAdministrator\.nuget\packages\'.
```

The build pipeline has a task

```
- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: '**\*.sln'
    feedsToUse: config

    nugetConfigPath: 'myproject/nuget.config'
```

The edited error is

```
   NU1000: Unable to find version 'myversion' of package 'mypackage'.
      C:\Users\VssAdministrator\.nuget\packages\: Package 'mypackage-versionumber' is not found on source 'C:\Users\VssAdministrator\.nuget\packages\'.
      myfeed/nuget/v3/index.js: The V2 feed at 'myfeed/nuget/v3/index.js/FindPackagesById()?id='mypackage'&semVerLevel=2.0.0' returned an unexpected status code '404 Not Found'.
      https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json: Package 'mypackage' is not found on source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json'.
```

Why would the error mention a V2 feed?

In VS2017 15.9.7 Help About, I see that NuGet Package Manager is 4.6.0

I wonder if it could be an access issue.
In Devops the project containing the package feed is in the same organisation as the consuming project.

Comment: https://medium.com/@DomBurf/consuming-a-private-nuget-feed-in-an-azure-devops-build-pipeline-e3b9d785cfd5

Comment: https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/4860

Comment: researching "The V2 feed at 'https://pkgs.dev.azure.com returned an unexpected status code "

Comment: Changing the major variable in the build pipeline for the packages from 1 to 2

Comment: What is `myfeed/nuget/v3/index.js`? Is the path of your private Azure Artifacts feed? It should be a `index.json` file instead of `index.js` file. If possible, please double check the path.

Comment: ah cut and paste error... testing now :-)

Comment: @LeoLiu-MSFT  That was the answer. Care to write it up? I think it is useful to know... I will fix the question to highlight the error.

Comment: That is OK, I will convert the comment to the answer, so that it would be helpful to anyone who encounters similar issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Configure Devops to use packages from private Azure Artifacts feed

Your YAML file and configuration steps are correct. I test it on my side and it works fine, but I found that your private Nuget packages feed path does not seem to be incorrect, so confirm with you by comments.

The path should be `.json` file. We could copy it from Azure Artifacts feed with connect to feed button:

[image]

Post it as answer, hope it would be helpful to anyone who encounters similar issues.

Thanks also to the confirmation of @Kirsten Greed.